# VS2015 MVC No compile experience

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

It was my understanding that with the new compiler it is possible to run code without restarting an ASP.NET MVC project, e.g. the no-compile experience.

For example changing the model or controller requires restarting the entire project, which can take quite some time in VS2013 (especially with Code First).

Is this, basically edit&continue for ASP.NET, now possible in VS2015? I tried CTP5 but could not get this working.

Edit: The actual question

Does VS2015, or will it, support edit and continue or a similar experience (not having to restart for model/controller changes) for ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: So what *exactly* is your question?

Comment: I added a clear question :)

Comment: Yes Visual Studio 2015 supports it, but you have to run your project using Debug->Start without debugging for it to work. 

If you run the project using the Start button it runs in debug mode and that doesn't support the change and auto-compile. Which makes sense, you shouldn't change code during a debug session.

Comment: This works in VS2013 too, never realized this. However losing my debug session kind of defeats the purpose, which is why edit & continue is so great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does VS2015, or will it, support edit and continue or a similar experience (not having to restart for model/controller changes) for ASP.NET MVC?

Visual Studio `Edit and Continue` is available and works for ASP.Net all the way back to version 2010 with constraints (IIS Express etc...).

> Is this, basically edit&continue for ASP.NET

No.  Scott Hanselman did a very detailed explanation of all the new features in vNext in this blog post [Introducing ASP.NET vNext](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETVNext.aspx).

Excerpt:

> One of the great aspects of environments like node or rails is that they are "no compile." Just change some code and hit refresh. With the next version of ASP.NET you get the power and throughput of the .NET runtime plus the "Roslyn" compiler-as-a-service for a "no-compile compile." That means means during development time you can just change your C# classes and hit Refresh in the browser. It's the power of .NET with the dynamism of a refresh-and-go development experience.

and

> **NOTE**: This isn't ASP.NET Websites, or Razor View compilation - this is the whole thing, compiled in memory. You can use Visual Studio for development, or text editors like Sublime, or freakin' Notepad. (Of course, if you want assemblies on disk, you can do that too.)

and

> See my web app’s bin folder in the screenshot below? There’s no assemblies in there because the assemblies never exist on the disk. It’s actually faster and easier to have the compiler do all the work in memory.

Comment: Great! And thanks for the article. But I guess the "no-compile compile" is not in CTP5 yet? I see this feature everywhere but not on the preview pages, so I'm guessing its not ready for testing yet.

Comment: I don't have any personal experience with the "no-compile experience" but I would assume its enabled by default and there is no flags to set (based on his comment you could use notepad).  I'd also assume it's already available as Scotts blog post was now almost a year ago.